# classes and methods in python

Tags: python, class, function, testing, python-2.7

```
import unittest
from paycheck import with_checker

class TestStrings(unittest.TestCase):        
    @with_checker([int])
    def test_sort(self, list_of_ints):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(list_of_ints, list))
        self.assertTrue(len(list_of_ints) == len(qsort(list_of_ints)))
        self.assertTrue(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

    def qsort (list):
        if list == []:
            return []
        else:
            pivot = list [0]
            lesser = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x<pivot])
            greater = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x>=pivot])
            return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

This gives me `global name qsort not defined` (even if i have it in the same class). What is the problem here? I suppose it is simple, but I'm not yet very familiar with Python.

Comment: I guess there is a reason for using your own `qsort` instead of Python's `sorted()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running the tests before you define the function.  Function definitions in Python are executable statements like any other and are executed in the order they're encountered.  Since you call `unittest.main()` before you define `qsort`, `qsort` is not defined when the test is run.  Move your `unittest.main()` call after the `def qsort` block.

While you're at it, it's better not to put the `def` inside the `if __name__=="__main__"` block anyway.  Usually that if block will be the last bit in your program.  Just do

```
def qsort (list):
    if list == []:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = list [0]
        lesser = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x<pivot])
        greater = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x>=pivot])
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Also note that qsort is not "in the same class" as anything.  It's not in any class.  It's just a function.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should read up on functions in python coming from a Java background :)

Answer (score 1):

The dedent at `if __name__...` signifies the end of the class definition. You should move those two lines to the bottom, qsort is now part of your class

```
import unittest
from paycheck import with_checker

class TestStrings(unittest.TestCase):        
    @with_checker([int])
    def test_sort(self, list_of_ints):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(list_of_ints, list))
        self.assertTrue(len(list_of_ints) == len(qsort(list_of_ints)))
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def qsort (list):
        if list == []:
            return []
        else:
            pivot = list [0]
            lesser = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x<pivot])
            greater = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x>=pivot])
            return lesser + [pivot] + greater

if __name__ == '__main__':   # move these two lines
    unittest.main()          # to the bottom
```

Comment: If you move `qsort` to the class you need `self` when calling it from inside.

Comment: @Matthias, True. I won't make those changes here as it doesn't address the immediate question.

Comment: Well I guess it somewhat does, as I still get the NameError if i have it on the same indentation level as the test, if i put it at "indentation 0" i get no error and it works,

Comment: @Vixen, sure if you put it in the global namespace it will work (and probably makes more sense to do so)